# Internal message/ note platform

Tags: php, mysql

I am looking to implement a system which allows our internal team to write notes about a specific customer and 'tag' another employee if action is required. If an employee is tagged, they are alerted of a new message. Every time an employee logs into the online system, their homepage/dashboard displays all new messages tagged to them.

My site is built on a LAMP stack. Are there any good scripts or software to implement for such a system?

Answer (score 0):

do you have an existing CRM or help-desk suite?  If so, you might try hunting for plugins there.  I know most CRM packages have a follow-up/action-item feature that does this...

if you're dealing with a custom-brewed app, shoe-horning in a third-party solution is going to be rough... probably best to just code it yourself.

Cheers!